# Convergence almost everywhere of sum.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral

Consider $\{r_{n}\}_{n \ge 1}$ set of all rational numbers of $[0,1]$.

Now lets define $$\displaystyle S_{k}(x) := \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n^{2} \sqrt{|x-r_{n}|}}$$

My question is : does $S_k(x)$ converge almost everywhere on $[0,1]$\ $\mathbb{Q}$?

I thought about considering $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}  \int_{[0,1]} S_{k}(x)\, dx$ and use Lebesgue theorem about limit under integration. Then if exact result is converges , I could say if my series converges **a.e.** or not. Am I right?

However , can we say something about this series without Lebesgue integral?

Comment: @Shashi my bad. Edited

Comment: nice! {} {} {} {} {}

Comment: I also add some edits I hope you find them fine.

Comment: In order to apply the dominated convergence theorem, we need convergence of the sequence. That is one of the requirements of the theorem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the $S_k(x)$ is pointwise monotone-inscreasing, we may use the montone convergence theorem to conclude that
$$ \int_0^1 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n(x) \mathop{dx} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}} \mathop{dx} \leq 4 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} <\infty.$$
Thus, $S(x) := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n(x) < \infty$ for $\lambda$-almost all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: I don't get the last estimate. Would you please provide some explanations?

Comment: We have $\int_0^1 |x-r_n|^{-1/2} \mathop{dx} = \left. -2 \sqrt{r_n -x} \right|_{x=0}^{r-n} +  \left. 2 \sqrt{x -r_n} \right|_{x=r_n}^{1} =  2 (\sqrt{1-r_n} + \sqrt{r_n}) \leq 4$.

Comment: thanks I see it!